# How handling relationships in CoreData while retrieving data from JSON + Swift Or ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data, swift

I actually want to handle relationships while i parsing Json data and creat the childs object, save and manage the relations.

I use findOrCreat function to verify if my object exist already or not, if it exsit i do update from JSON data, and if not, i create the object. as i use NSAsynchnonusFetchRequest i don't have any idea to how handling the relations. Also, the relations must be created before the parent object, so when i creat the parent in asynchronus call , how can i manage the creation of the childs and relations ?

here you can find my findOrCreat function :

```
// Asynchronous fetch
    let asyncFetch = NSAsynchronousFetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest) {
        (result:NSAsynchronousFetchResult!)-> Void in
        if result.finalResult!.count <= 0 {
            var eventToSave:Events!;
            eventToSave = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(Entities.Event.rawValue, inManagedObjectContext: self.cdhUser.backgroundContext!) as Events;
            eventToSave.setValue(eventId, forKey: "id");
            eventToSave.setValue((dictionary.objectForKey("title") as NSString), forKey: "title");
            eventToSave.setValue((dictionary.objectForKey("exclusive") as Bool), forKey: "isExclusive");
            eventToSave.setValue(0, forKey: "latitude");
            eventToSave.setValue(0, forKey: "longitude");
            eventToSave.setValue("", forKey: "details");
            eventToSave.setValue((dictionary.objectForKey("summary") as NSString), forKey: "summary");
            eventToSave.setValue((NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: dictionary.objectForKey("date") as Double)), forKey: "date");
            eventToSave.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "validFrom");
            eventToSave.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "validTo");

            // Get url of image
            var pictureUrl:NSString!;
            if let pictureDictionary:NSDictionary = dictionary.objectForKey("main_media") as? NSDictionary {
                if let endUrlString:NSString = pictureDictionary.objectForKey("url") as? NSString {
                    pictureUrl = endUrlString;
                }
            }
            eventToSave.setValue((pictureUrl != nil ? pictureUrl : ""), forKey: "picture"); // Default Image Url

            self.cdhUser.saveContext(self.cdhUser.backgroundContext!);
        }
        else if result.finalResult!.count > 0 {
            var eventToUpdate = result.finalResult?.first as Events;
            eventToUpdate.setValue((dictionary.objectForKey("title") as NSString), forKey: "title");
            eventToUpdate.setValue((dictionary.objectForKey("exclusive") as Bool), forKey: "isExclusive");
            eventToUpdate.setValue(0, forKey: "longitude");
            eventToUpdate.setValue(0, forKey: "latitude");
            eventToUpdate.setValue("", forKey: "details");
            eventToUpdate.setValue((dictionary.objectForKey("summary") as NSString), forKey: "summary");
            eventToUpdate.setValue((NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: dictionary.objectForKey("date") as Double)), forKey: "date");
            eventToUpdate.setValue((NSDate()), forKey: "validTo");
            eventToUpdate.setValue((NSDate()), forKey: "validFrom");

            // Get url of image
            var pictureUrl:NSString!;
            if let pictureDictionary:NSDictionary = dictionary.objectForKey("main_media") as? NSDictionary {
                if let endUrlString:NSString = pictureDictionary.objectForKey("url") as? NSString {
                    pictureUrl = endUrlString;
                }
            }
            eventToUpdate.picture = pictureUrl;
            println(eventToUpdate);
            self.cdhUser.saveContext(self.cdhUser.backgroundContext!);
            NSLog("Update is done!");
        }
    }
    self.cdhUser.backgroundContext!.performBlock {
        var result = self.cdhUser.backgroundContext!.executeRequest(asyncFetch, error: &error) as NSAsynchronousFetchResult;
    }
}
```

And here is an exemple of my JSON :

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "title": "Inauguration",
   "summary": "Evenement",
   "main_media": {
       "url": "c75b931abb131e9d091882c3638aca9fe0ecdee6.jpeg",
       "name": "99.JPG",
       "type": 2,
       "created_at": 1415377363
   },
   "date": 1412174799,
   "duration": 6483600,
   "exclusive": true,
   "geo_location": [],
   "open": true,
   "description": "Evenement",
   "interested": true,
   "medias": [{
       "url": "1c3f251b7bccd3bd4337852538fe7ba0accefa77.jpeg",
       "name": "b90mq.jpg",
       "type": 2,
       "created_at": 1415375677,
       "main_media": false
   }, {
       "url": "c75b931abb131e9d091882c3638aca9fe0ecdee6.jpeg",
       "name": "woodstock-99.JPG",
       "type": 2,
       "created_at": 1415377363,
       "main_media": true
   }]
```

}

So, How can i creat my Medias Object while creating my Events Object ? 
When can i call findOrCreate function to cerate Medias Object ? and how can manage relations ?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add one to many relationships in xcdatamodeld from Events to Media.

```
let manyRelation = eventToSave.valueForKeyPath("medias") as NSMutableSet
for dict : NSDictionary in dictionary.objectForKey("main_media") as? [NSDictionary] {
    let media : Media = Media()
    media.url = dict.objectForKey("url")
    media.name = dict.objectForKey("name")
    ....
    manyRelation.addObject(media)
}
```

This code need to add after creating root object and before saving context

Comment: Thanks alot. jsut one thing, i'm suppose to check if this media is already exist or not!? for that, i have to call findOrCreate function for Medias.. what do you think about ?

Comment: there are two solutions: 1) u can find and update created object 2) u can remove all existing objects and recreate them. in your case the second solution approachs and is more simple than first.

Comment: Thanks alot, i will do it .

Comment: I Got : 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Media setPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19b676e0'
I think it's because there is no object "Media" created in CoreData... we didn't setEntitiyDescription(Media...) ! what do you think about ?! thanks for your help

Comment: I mean : NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(...)!

Comment: Yes, you should use insertNewObjectForEntityForName. (You can add it in init method of Media) You should add one to many relationships in xcdatamodeld from Events to Media. - it means you need create Media entity in xcdatamodeld.

Comment: Yes it is. I already did it ( create Media entity in xcdatamodeld ). Thanks for your help.